# My bootstrap row and column occupied same space it doesn't adjust size automatically

Tags: html, css, row

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="welcome-tag">
    <p> Create a Havedocs Account to discover </p>
  </div>
  <div class="logInfDiv">
    <div class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i></div>
    <div class="media-body"> <strong>Access Quality Content</strong><br>
      Browse and download millions of crowd-sourced study materials tagged to specific courses at universities all over the world </div>
  </div>
  <div class="logInfDiv">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
      <div class="media-body"> <strong>Study Whenever You Want</strong><br>
        Havedocs's services are available 24/7 - you can ask a tutor for homework help at 3 a.m. or review flashcards over lunch </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="logInfDiv">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></div>
      <div class="media-body"> <strong>Build a Better Community</strong><br>
        Share educational content with fellow students to make Havedocs stronger and earn free Premier membership </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form class="form-signin">
    <div class="login_heading">
      <div class="headingLeft"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Create an Account</div>
      <div class="headingRight"><a href="login.php">Login</a></div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" placeholder="User Name" required autofocus />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailAddress" placeholder="Email Address" required autofocus />
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required/>
    <br>
    <label>Gender</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>
    Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
    Female<br>
    <br>
    <div class="create-acc">
      <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php"> Click here Login.</a></p>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Register</button>
  </form>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code and screenshot attached! I'm using row then col-lg-12 and they are with same space and doesn't adjust accordingly with content ,the signup form goes down and hides when i make some fields and the scroll option doesn't come please let me know where i'm doing wrong thanks

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/RMJjK     here is screenshot

Comment: add your custom css & also add code js fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide your page into 2 sections Left and right
on right side you can use ur login form

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="welcome-tag">
        <p> Create a Havedocs Account to discover </p>
      </div>

      <div class="logInfDiv">
        <div class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i></div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <strong>Access Quality Content</strong>
          <br>
          Browse and download millions of crowd-sourced study materials tagged to specific courses at universities all over the world
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="logInfDiv">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <strong>Study Whenever You Want</strong><br>
            Havedocs's services are available 24/7 - you can ask a tutor for homework help at 3 a.m. or review flashcards over lunch
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="logInfDiv">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <strong>Build a Better Community</strong><br>
        Share educational content with fellow students to make Havedocs stronger and earn free Premier membership
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div> <!------- left side ends
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">          
      <form class="form-signin">
        <div class="login_heading">
          <div class="headingLeft"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Create an Account</div>
          <div class="headingRight"><a href="login.php">Login</a></div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" placeholder="User Name" required="" autofocus="" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailAddress" placeholder="Email Address" required="" autofocus="" />
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required=""/>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required=""/><br>
        <label>Gender</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br><br>

        <div class="create-acc">
          <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php"> Click here Login.</a></p>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```